# Using @Query fetches unrequested data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String food;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String time;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Post.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
}
```

User.java

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {
    /**
     * Find All Posts
     * @return
     */
    @Query(value="SELECT a.id, a.food, a.time, a.city, a.user_id, b.username FROM POST a INNER JOIN USER b ON a.user_id = b.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Post> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();

    /**
     * Find All By City Search
     * @param city
     * @return
     */
    @Query(value="SELECT a.id, a.food, a.time, a.city, a.user_id, b.username FROM POST a INNER JOIN USER b ON a.user_id = b.id WHERE UPPER(a.city) LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(:city),'%')", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Post> findAllByCityOrderByIdDesc(@Param("city") String city);
}
```

PostRepository.java

As you can see, I'm trying to fetch data from Post table inner joined with User table but it fetches not only requested data from specified columns above but all the user info including password.
Why does it happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that more gets fetched than you are requesting?

Answer (score 0):

The findAllByOrderByIdDesc() method is JPA repository method it will fetch all Post data with user information also.
Use some specific name for method. And your are retrieving 5 columns so you can not assign return type as List.

Write query as below and try.
@Query(value="SELECT a.id, a.food, a.time, a.city, a.user_id,  b.username FROM POST a INNER JOIN USER b ON a.user_id = b.id", nativeQuery = true)
Listt<Object[]> getallPost();